# How to check entered value is exist or not using Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one textbox and one button and on button I have written below code. problem is suppose first I have entered in textbox 10 than its worked but when another time I enter 10 than also it prints value is not in array. so pls help me whats the issue...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
 jQuery("#mybutton").live('click',function () 
 {
    var sel_fam_rel=jQuery("#my_textbox").val();
    var ids = [];
    code =sel_fam_rel;
    if($.inArray(code,ids) >= 0)
    {
      alert("Value is in array");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Value is not in array");
      ids.push(code);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You are re-initializing `ids`, So it will always go to else section. Show us your compete JS code.

Comment: `if($.inArray(code,ids) != -1)` isn't this would be there?

Comment: i have added but still same issue getting. jai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if($.inArray(code,ids) >= 0)
```

should be changed to:

```
if($.inArray(code,ids) != -1)
```

and put your ids var outside of click.

Try the snippet below.

```js
var ids = [];
jQuery("button").on('click', function() {
  var sel_fam_rel = jQuery("#my_textbox").val();

  code = sel_fam_rel;
  if ($.inArray(code, ids) != -1) {
    alert("Value is in array");
  } else {
    alert("Value is not in array");
    ids.push(code);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='my_textbox'>
<button>check</button>
```

Comment: What difference does it make if it is `>=0` or `!=-1`?

Comment: @charlietfl `!=-1` , seems to better convey the intent to me, but good point

Comment: @DelightedD0D that is purely subjective. The only difference here that matters is storing the array outside the click handler

Comment: Should the OP not also be encouraged to use `on()` or `.delegate()` over `live()`?

Answer (score 1):

use below code . take your ids out side of click event . as per your code each time when you click button ids reset .

```
var ids = [];  // declare as global variable
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery("#mybutton").live('click',function () 
  {
    var sel_fam_rel=jQuery("#my_textbox").val();
    code =sel_fam_rel;
    if($.inArray(code,ids) >= 0)
    {
     alert("Value is in array");
    }
   else
   {
     alert("Value is not in array");
     ids.push(code);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: shouldn't the OP be encouraged to use `on()` over `live()`?

Comment: thanks... in above code if i change this line of code  if($.inArray(code,ids) != -1) instead of if($.inArray(code,ids) >= 0) than only it will be worked..

Comment: @MahendraPumbhadiya its not like you change it >= 0 to != -1 this both condition is same. it work because you put ids = [] out side of click event .

Answer (score 1):

Create your array `var ids=[];`global outside button event, as whenever you click button it is creating new empty array. It will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A few changes are needed:

```js
var ids = []; // `ids` needs to be in the global scope to work as you want it, 
              //  or you could use a different method like localstorage 
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
 jQuery("#mybutton").on('click',function () // use `on` not `live` which is deprecated
 {
    var sel_fam_rel=jQuery("#my_textbox").val();
    code =sel_fam_rel;
    if($.inArray(code,ids) != -1)  // inArray() returns -1 if the value is not in the array, you can use it the way you have it, IMO (purely subjective), using `!=-1` is preferable as it's more clear what the code in intend to do
    {
      alert("Value is in array");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Value is not in array");
      ids.push(code);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="my_textbox" value="10"/><br>
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Click me"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a fiddle to your problem, Use `indexOf`

http://jsfiddle.net/go8o34fq/

**jQuery-**

```
var array=["A","B","C","D"];

$('button').click(function(){
    var code=$('input').val();
    if(array.indexOf(code)==-1)
    {
        array.push(code);
       console.log("if "+array)
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("else "+array)
    }
});
```

Just a bit requirement if your need is case-sensitive then use- `code.toUpperCase()`

Comment: -1 because you tell the OP to use `indexOf` (which is not really the issue). and while you do change the scope of the array (which was the problem), you dont mention that in your answer